# Keras - 1D Convolution How it works

Tags: neural-network, convolution, keras

From this example: 
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py

comes this snippet below. The embedding layer outputs a 400 x 50 matrix for each example in a batch. My question is how does the 1D convolution work? How does it work across the 400 x 50 matrix?

```
# we start off with an efficient embedding layer which maps
# our vocab indices into embedding_dims dimensions
model.add(Embedding(max_features,
                    embedding_dims,
                    input_length=maxlen,
                    dropout=0.2))

# we add a Convolution1D, which will learn nb_filter
# word group filters of size filter_length:
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                        filter_length=filter_length,
                        border_mode='valid',
                        activation='relu',
                        subsample_length=1))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In convolutional neural networks (CNNs), 1D and 2D filters are not really 1 and 2 dimensional. It is a convention for description.

In your example, each 1D filter is actually a Lx50 filter, where L is a parameter of filter length. The convolution is only performed in one dimension. That may be why it is called 1D. So, with proper padding, each 1D filter convolution gives a 400x1 vector. The Convolution1D layer will eventually output a matrix of 400*`nb_filter`.

Comment: Can we conceptualize this then as creating at each step, a dot product of L words (the first L, then slide and include words 2:2+L, etc) where the dot product is done for the complete embedding (50 values) of L words each time?

Comment: Yes, each output value of the convolution is actually a dot product of L*50 embedding values with the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a background of signal processing it also took me while to understand the concept of it and it seems to be the case of many people in the community.

[Pyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111778/pyan) gave a very good explanation. As it is often explained with words in many forums, I made a little animation the I hope will help.

See below the input tensor, the filter (or weight) and the outputed tensor. You can also see the size of the output tensor as a function of the number of filters used (represented with different colours).

[Visual Representation of the 1D Convolultion (Simplified)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfPbm.gif)

Note that to perform the scalar multiplication between the input and the filter, the filter should be transposed. There are also different implementations (Karas, Tensorflow, Pytorch...), but I think this animation can give a good representation of what is happening.

Hope it can help someone.